# Why does the following sql produce nil in IRB

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, irb

I am running this in IRB

```
sql = "SELECT to_tsvector(part_groups.name) as document FROM part_groups GROUP BY part_groups.name;"

doc = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

puts doc.inspect
```

> => nil

For sanity I did this and I also get nil

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM part_groups where id > 1;"
```

Comment: just `SELECT * FROM "part_groups"`?

Comment: Have you tried that SQL inside `psql`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the connection has already been established? Or is `connection` also `nil`?

The [*ActiveRecord*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) doc states that `connection` is generally used to retrieve an already established connection, while `establish_connection` is used to first connect:

> Connections are usually created through
>   `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` and retrieved by
>   `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`. All classes inheriting from
>   `ActiveRecord::Base` will use this connection.